# R empty string replacement

Tags: r, string, replace, dataframe

I should convert ‘N/A’ and ‘not known’ to a blank string “”

```
   Var1     Freq
1  N/A       650
2  NONE      264
3  NOT KNOWN  58
```

to be like this

```
Var1  Freq
1      650
2      264
3      58
```

and

```
"" <- new_building[grepl("N/A|NOT|KNOWN", new_building$Var1),]
```

I used this but this is not working

Comment: Why is "NONE" removed if you only want to remove "N/A" or "NOT KNOWN"?

Answer (score 1):

```
> string<-'asdaN/A'
> string2<-gsub(string,pattern='N/A',replacement='')
> string2
 [1] "asda"
```

do you mean this?

Edit: following updated q:

```
string<-c('Var1','Freq', '1','N/A','650','2', 'NONE','264', '3', 'NOT KNOWN', '58')
string[!string%in%'N/A']
```

Comment: my problem is I have to save the blank as a data

Comment: that is not clear from your question. you want a vector of the same length but with blanks where the N/A is, then you can get that from what I've given you so far. Or can you update what your desired output looks like

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
df_ <- data.frame(Var1 = c('N/A', 'NONE', 'NOT KNOWN'), Freq = c(650, 264, 58))

df_$Var1 <- gsub("N/A|NONE|NOT KNOWN", "", df_$Var1)
df_

#  Var1 Freq
#1       650
#2       264
#3        58
```

your assignment to `""` (`"" <- ...`) is very wrong; i am not sure what your logic is here. the correct approach is to substitute strings satisfying your criteria with empty strings `""` using `gsub`.